# How to properly make sense of Android's onScroll GestureDetector method?

Tags: android, scroll, onscroll, gesturedetector, onfling

After several StackOverflow posts and Android's [onScroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onScroll(android.view.MotionEvent,%2520android.view.MotionEvent,%2520float,%2520float)) documentation, I am still unable to make sense of how onScroll method works.

**Context and What I am trying to achieve:** I have a webview with mostly texts in it. I am overriding webview's default scrolling behavior, and instead trying to take control of the scrolling mechanism. I want to be able to -

1. Scroll by a paragraph length with a fling gesture. I am able to do that by calling Android's `onFling` method.
2. Scroll to next sentence with a drag gesture. This is where I am struggling.

From the definition of drag gesture (plus scrolling gesture) in Android, the difference between drag and fling is that, for fling, the user's finger has to leave the surface with a velocity. Having said that, I see that onScroll is called multiple times and onFling only once. I guess that is okay. What I am struggling to understand is what does the parameters do in onScroll method?

I don't quite understand the purpose of `event1`, `event2`, `distanceX`, and `distanceY` - if all of them change each time `onScroll` is called. How do you make sense of these parameters? What is the proper way of interpreting them? Android documentation did not help.

**UPDATE**

I logged my touch movements, and here is how it looks.

Movement: Dragging vertically up without lifting the finger

```
event 1 X=600.64453, Y=891.5178
event 2 X=594.5489, Y=891.5178
event 1 X=600.64453, Y=886.3
event 2 X=593.7481, Y=886.3
event 1 X=600.64453, Y=879.9082
event 2 X=592.97614, Y=879.9082
```

Question: Since I moved vertically up, I expect most of my changes in Y axis, and very minimal in X axis. What I see here is that, for event 1, X is always the same, however, Y keeps changing. If event 1 is the first down motion that started the scrolling, shouldn't Y still be the same? But even then, how do you explain why for any pair of {event 1, event 2} here, Xs are different whereas Ys are same? Shouldn't it be the opposite?

Movement: Dragging horizontally from left to right.

```
event 1 X=340.66406, Y=861.7873
event 2 X=374.05276, Y=861.7873
event 1 X=340.66406, Y=862.9392
event 2 X=382.84317, Y=862.9392
event 1 X=340.66406, Y=864.10034
event 2 X=390.39926, Y=864.10034
```

Question: Intuition says, movement in horizontal direction should trigger most changes in X axis and minor changes in Y axis. Here, all event 1 Xs are same, but Y is different. Again, I expected both X and Y to be same! For any pair of {event 1, event 2}, Xs are different whereas Ys are same. This sounds normal, but then again, if I look back to the one above, I am getting confused. How do you distinguish them?

Thanks and my apology for a long verbose question!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
/**
  * Notified when a scroll occurs with the initial on down {@link MotionEvent} and the
  * current move {@link MotionEvent}. The distance in x and y is also supplied for
  * convenience.
  *
  * @param e1 The first down motion event that started the scrolling.
  * @param e2 The move motion event that triggered the current onScroll.
  * @param distanceX The distance along the X axis that has been scrolled since the last
  *              call to onScroll. This is NOT the distance between {@code e1}
  *              and {@code e2}.
  * @param distanceY The distance along the Y axis that has been scrolled since the last
  *              call to onScroll. This is NOT the distance between {@code e1}
  *              and {@code e2}.
  * @return true if the event is consumed, else false
  */
  boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY);
```

`e1`: Since this is the motion event that triggered the scroll, you can expect this to stay the same throughout your scroll.

`e2`: A user could move their finger around the screen in multiple directions without lifting it and `onScroll` would be called separately for each change it detects. This is pretty sensitive, so that's why you're seeing onScroll called multiple times.

`distanceX` and `distanceY` aren't your total distances traveled, but only the distances since the last time onScroll was called. You can calculate your net distances by comparing the `getX()` and `getY()` methods on each MotionEvent.

If all you need to do is check that a scroll was initiated, this is probably more info than you need. You could try and trigger your event only when you receive a unique `event1`

Comment: Thanks @rhpekarek. I have updated my question with log data. I expected e1 to stay the same, but unfortunately, I am finding it otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange that the Y value is changing. It looks like it's recalibrating once it knows more about the path the scroll is taking and matching the Y to the latest position you see in `e2`. The X value does look like it's staying the same though. Maybe you could rely on that for uniqueness?

Comment: I guess I can. But its not a good way of interpreting it, is it? At least, the way it is doesn't match with what we see in Android documentation.

Comment: Could you try logging what your event 1 `getAction()` is? I think you may be able to filter down to what you're looking for based on that. It looks like the MotionEvents with action type `ACTION_MOVE` are batching a series of coordinates, with `getX()` and `getY()` being the most recent: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#batching